# NumPy: How to most efficiently/idiomatically add a value to all items in an array after an index?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to add a value to all items of a 1-D array after a certain index.

For example, my original array looks like this:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

and I want to add 1 to all items after index 2, to end up with the following result array:

```
[0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

What is the most efficient way to do this, in terms of performance and use of 'idiomatic' Python/NumPy (i.e. not using a loop)? It seems that a list comprehension isn't the best approach since I'm dealing with NumPy arrays -- my assumption is that there's a clever way to index the array for this instead that may also be more performant.

Here's what I've cooked up using a list comprehension:

```
ary = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
ix = 3
ary[ix:] = [x + 1 for x in ary[ix:]]
```

Is there a better way to do this, or is this good enough?

Comment: .. `a[3:] += 1`?

Comment: You should make a distinction here between python and numpy. Although numpy is a python library, the array object supports a huge range of efficient methods. It doesn't really resemble a regular python list. On the python side, your list comprehension is still a loop, there's no reason it will automatically be more performant than a regular `for` loop

Comment: @Divakar has provided the answer, thanks!

Comment: @roganjosh makes a very good point/clarification, confirming my suspicion that a list comprehension isn't the best for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To add a `value` to all elements of an array `ary` at and after index `ix`:

```
ary[ix:] += value
```

Comment: Answer originally provided in a comment by @Divakar